# Selenium WebDriver - cssselector for locating input + onclick

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I have the following checkbox:

```
<input id="outerLabor102" name="ctl02$chkSelectLabor" onclick="chkChildLabor(this);chkIntervallineChild(this);" type="checkbox">
```

I'm more of an xpath guy but since I want to come up with a selector that will find that checkbox by the input id PLUS the onclick attribute, I think a css selector should do just fine, but I can't find a way to formulate one.

I was thinking of something like:

```
(By.cssSelector("input[id=outerLabor102]input[onclick^=chkChildLabor(this);chkIntervallineChild(this);]")
```

Thanks for checking out my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not rely on the `onclick` attribute, but, for the sake of an example:

```
input#outerLabor102[onclick^=chkChildLabor]
```

where `^=` is a *starts-with* notation.